# How to place a constant symbol in an html field

Tags: html, css

I have an html input field

```
<input name="expiry" type="text" placeholder="MM/YY"/>
```

I need to put a "/" so that if a user enters a value "06" ,it should be behind the "/" like "06/  " and after that when he enters the year "13",it should automatically be in the right side of the "/" like "06/13".I want the "/" to stay as constant and if the user fills the MM with a 2 digit the cursor should jumb into the right side of the "/" waiting for the next input.

Comment: Could you do this with two input controls and some JavaScript? The slash can be placed between them, so the user just enters four numbers, with the cursor jumping to the second box after the second number has been entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/59hS8/)**</kbd>

```
<input name="expiry" type="text" placeholder="MM/YY" maxlength="5"/>

$('input').on('keyup',function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9/]/g, '')); // Validation
  if($(this).val().length === 2) {
     $(this).val($(this).val() + '/');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With javascript (jQuery), look at mask plugins:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 0):

you will need 2 inputs, one for the months and another for the years, with a / between

Comment: I guess i cando that.But I thinkthe question is not clear to u.I want it in a single field

Comment: @AjeeshAchuthan using only html and css it's not possible. you could try a jquery plugin as FBHY says

Answer (score 0):

On a different note:

There has been an addition to the HTML5, the *year-and-month input control*.

`<input type=month...`

More Info: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.month.html

> The input element with a type attribute whose value is "month"
>   represents a control for setting the element’s value to a string
>   representing a month.

Check this example which is exactly your use-case: http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/#input-month

It is currently supported in Opera, Chrome and Safari. Chrome and Safari recognize this tag, but show no UI.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input